# Where do files created in Django go?

Tags: django

I have a view where I create a file (call it .something.txt). I see that I can access it from another view as well. Also, it is in the same folder where I have my manage.py. I am trying to understand whether someone from outside can have access to this unencrypted file and how they can get it?

Is what I am doing safe, from a privacy perspective, if I store the data as an encrypted text file in the same way?

Comment: There are many, many ways a system can be breached.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out if it is possible to read this file from my webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is it's *probably* safe, but it depends on how you've configured your web server.

Django isn't served like a PHP site where the web server reads the code directly from the same place as the HTML, JS and CSS files. Rather, it uses a wsgi server to run the code. So there is no need to put the code files themselves into the Apache webroot, for example. Because of this, there is little danger that the file could be requested directly from outside. But it's not impossible; there are plenty of ways to misconfigure a webserver like Apache or Nginx that would make the file available externally.